# Rank of a k-tree

Tags: tree, pseudocode

I need to make a function which calcolate the rank of a k-tree. I wrote it so:

```
Rank (T)
if T.child=NIL
    return 0
else 
   return 1+ max{Rank(T.child), Rank(T.sibiling)}
end if
```

Is it correct? The max function calculates the max between the number of the left and the right node of the tree.

Comment: Is this pseudo code? because this is definitly not java

Comment: Sorry, I removed the Java tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with K-trees so correct me if I go wrong.

The rank is the number of nodes smaller than the root you are looking up if I understand correctly. So you need to balance your tree in such a way that all subsequent trees to a child-node are less than the the local root.

After that you need to do a in-order traversal of the tree. The first node you visit should be the smallest one, and be given a rank of 0, next node visited should be given a rank of 1 and so forth.

Example code:

```
private int getRank(Node<E> n, E target, int rank) {
    if (n == null)
        return rank;
    rank = getRank(n.left, target, rank);   // smaller nodes
    if (n.e.equals(target))     // Solution to sought after node (target) 
        return rank;    
    System.out.println(n.e + " has rank " + rank);
    return getRank(n.right, target, rank + 1);  // larger nodes
}
public int getRank(E target) {
    if (root != null) {
        return getRank(root, target, 0);
    }
    return -1;
}



OUT:
3 has rank 0
4 has rank 1
5 has rank 2
7 has rank 3
9 has rank 4
```

An alternative solution, if the tree isn't balanced is to visit all nodes and count nodes that are smaller than the target node.

Example:

```
private int getRank(Node<E> n, E target, int count) {
    if (n != null) {
        for (Node<E> c : getChildren(n)) {
            count += getRank(c, target, count);
        }
        if (n.e.compareTo(target) < 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```